# Custom (re)ordering of legend/bar segments in Einstein Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, charts, order, orderitem

**Question:**

Currently I can sort bar segments of a stacked column chart in asc/desc order or keep it unsorted. However I would like to sort them in a custom fashion like in the image. How to do it with custom SAQL or XMD?

[image: Reordering Bar Segments]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

I used an approach using the SAQL mode. However I also wanted to get rid of the numbers in the legend. Therefore I edited the XMD .json file as well.

[**Here is my complete answer to the question.**](http://www.aydincanpolatkan.com/blog/2527)