# Custom (re)ordering and modification of legend in origami charts of Einstein Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, einstein-analytics-dashboards

[Custom (re)ordering of legend/bar segments in Einstein Analytics](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227198/custom-reordering-of-legend-bar-segments-in-einstein-analytics#)

Above is the current workaround solution for custom (re)ordering of legend bar segments in Einstein Analytics.

I've managed to attain my desired order of attributes for the said origami chart. However, I'm having a hard time editing out the appended numbers on the display portion (JSON file) of the chart.

Example:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!